# Can the Interval be Covered by Disjoint Cantor Sets?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

I looked in a couple of books focusing on set theory in the real line, but I have not seen the proof or disproof of the following question.  It might be something easy just eluding me, but I wonder if the answer is no for reasons similar to why a continuous surjection from the Cantor Set $C$ onto $[0,1]$ is at least two-to-one.

The question is: Can the closed interval $I = [0,1]$ be partitioned into a collection of pairwise-disjoint copies of $C$?  A weaker version would be, can an uncountable union of pairwise-disjoint Cantor Sets merely contain an interval?  Can the union be equal to, or maybe just contain, $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Here, by a Cantor Set I mean any space homeomorphic to the standard ternary one.  So, any collection of totally disconnected, perfect, compact sets in $I$.

Thanks!

Edit:  In the same paper linked below, theorem 1.3 shows that $I \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ can be partitioned by Cantor Sets.  In fact, it shows that the Cantor Set can also be partitioned by homeomorphic copies of the irrationals.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by covering by copies of $C$? Do you mean having a closed covering of $[0,1]$ by traslations $C+x_n$?

Comment: No, just any Cantor Sets, not necessarily isometric.  I will clarify that really quick.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing: "Similarly, can an uncountable union of Cantor Sets ever cover any interval" -- uncountable and not necessarily disjoint?  Then, yes, of course.  You didn't mention countability condition before, did you mean it?

Comment: @Alexey, the second paragraph mentions that the sets should be disjoint.

Comment: Still assuming pairwise disjoint.  Is it obvious?

Comment: No, if they are disjoint, it is not clear.  If they are disjoint, then how is this question different from the previous one?

Comment: Maybe their union cannot be an interval, but could contain one.  The questions might be equivalent (probably are).  I have edited to clarify.

Comment: It is not my area of expertise, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A positive answer (that the interval can be partitioned into pairwise disjoint Cantor sets) is given by Theorem 1.14 of [Paul Bankston and Richard J. McGovern, Topological partitions, *General Topology and its Applications* **10** (1979), 215–229](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/%7Epaulb/Paper/toppart.pdf).

In fact any nonempty Polish space without isolated points can be partitioned into Cantor sets, according to the answer to this question:

[Partitioning a metric space into Cantor sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4162677/partitioning-a-metric-space-into-cantor-sets)

Comment: Doesn't 1.14 give a ZFC yes answer? no MA needed.

Comment: Wow, great paper!  I love the theorems on the Peano continua.  I think bof is saying that either CH or MA is sufficient.  The paper does not handle the case $X = I \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.  Is it open?

Comment: Oh yes, 1.14 does give the result with just ZFC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the comment. I've edited my answer accordingly.