# Can the quotient space obtained by partitioning the closed interval into Cantor sets be Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

In response to this question [Can the Interval be Covered by Disjoint Cantor Sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874786/can-the-interval-be-covered-by-disjoint-cantor-sets?rq=1) it was pointed out that the answer is, Yes: see Theorem 1.14 of Paul Bankston and Richard J. McGovern, Topological partitions, General Topology and its Applications 10 (1979), 215–229. [http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~paulb/Paper/toppart.pdf](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/%7Epaulb/Paper/toppart.pdf). Constructions seem to involve the Axiom of Choice (see the partial answer to this question: [Partitioning a metric space into Cantor sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4162677/partitioning-a-metric-space-into-cantor-sets?rq=1))

My question is: Let $I$ be the closed interval and $Q$ the quotient of $I$ by such a partition. Then $Q$ is a compact $T_1$ space. Can $Q$ be Hausdorff?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the constructions require the axiom of choice.  In the case of $I$, the construction given by Theorem 1.14 is close to explicit: you first take a sequence of disjoint Cantor sets whose union is dense, and then you identify the complement with $\mathbb{N}^\omega$ and cover that with copies of $\{0,1\}^\omega$ in the obvious way.  The only part of this that is not fully explicit is the identification of the complement with $\mathbb{N}^\omega$, but that should not be hard to make explicit.

Comment: A perhaps easier way to think about the question is: is there a continuous map $f:I\to X$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that every fiber of $f$ is a Cantor set?  (The obvious choice to try for $X$ would be $X=I$, but I haven't been able to find a construction that works.  It feels like this ought to be true in some sense for a "generic" map $I\to I$, but none of the usual methods I know of for making this precise seem to work, which suggests maybe it is not true.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I am most interested in the case when the closed interval is replaced by the 2-sphere (and I think that Choice is needed, or at least used, in the proof of that?) but I thought that I should pose this question for the simplest case. I had assumed that Choice was buried somewhere in 1.14 though I couldn't see it. Apologies!

Comment: @EricWofsey Is Andre Henriques' answer what you are looking for? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141853/partition-bbbr-into-a-family-of-sets-each-one-homeomorphic-to-the-cantor-se

Comment: That was actually an example I considered but it was not clear to me how to prove that every preimage really is a Cantor set.

Comment: I guess you can argue like this.  Letting $f:I\to I$ be the first coordinate of Hilbert's space-filling curve $h:I\to I^2$, we wish to show that no fiber of $f$ has an isolated point.  Now note that $h$ maps each dyadic interval in $I$ surjectively onto a dyadic square in $I^2$.  It follows that for any $t\in I$, any dyadic interval containing $t$ contains uncountably many points $t'$ such that $f(t)=f(t')$.  In particular, $t$ cannot be isolated in $f^{-1}(\{f(t)\})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h:I\to I^2$ be the [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).  In particular, this map $h$ has the following property: for each dyadic interval $J\subset I$ (i.e., an interval of the form $[k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n]$), the image $h(J)$ is a product of two dyadic intervals.  Let $f:I\to I$ be the first coordinate of $h$. Then $f$ is surjective and continuous, and thus a quotient map since $I$ is compact Hausdorff.  Also, $f$ is nowhere locally constant, and for each $t\in I$, every neighborhood of $t$ contains uncountably many points $t'$ such that $f(t)=f(t')$ (since it contains some dyadic interval containing $t$ and then the image of that dyadic interval under $h$ contains an entire vertical line segment containing $h(t)$).  Thus every fiber of $f$ is a Cantor set, so $f$ is a quotient map for a partition of $I$ into Cantor sets.